# Arithmetic on char in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am learning Java.

I am supposed to write a program that converts all uppercase letters to lowercase and all lowercase to uppercase. It said in the book I just need to subtract 32 from uppercase and add 32 to lowercase.

Here is my code...

```
class Caseconv {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.IOException {
            char ch;

            do {
            ch = (char) System.in.read();

            if (ch >= 97 & ch <= 122) ch = ch - 32;
            if (ch >= 65 & ch <= 90) ch = ch + 32;
            System.out.print(ch);
            } while (ch != '\n');
        }
}
```

But the compiler doesn't want to do this, I get this error.

```
Caseconv.java:13: error: possible loss of precision
            if (ch >= 97 & ch <= 122) ch = ch - 32;
                                              ^
  required: char
  found:    int
Caseconv.java:14: error: possible loss of precision
            if (ch >= 65 & ch <= 90) ch = ch + 32;
                                             ^
  required: char
  found:    int
2 errors
```

What am I supposed to be doing to subtract from the char?

Comment: Refer this below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411278/char-arithmetic-in-java/34411412#34411412

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a type cast to convert the result of the expression to `char`.  For example.

```
ch = (char)(ch + 32)
```

Notes:

1. The reason this is necessary is because `32` is an `int` literal, and the addition of a `char` and an `int` is performed using `int` arithmetic, and gives an `int` result.
2. Assigning an `int` to a `char` potentially results in truncation.  Adding the type cast effectively says to the compiler: *"Yes. I know.  It is OK.  Just do it."*
3. The parentheses around the `+` subexpression are necessary because type-cast has higher precedence than `+`.  If you leave them out, the type-cast makes no difference because it "casts" a `char` to a `char`.

Answer (score 3):

Type casting is required, try this code:

```
if (ch >= 97 & ch <= 122)
    ch = (char) (ch - 32);
if (ch >= 65 & ch <= 90)
    ch = (char) (ch + 32);
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of `arithmetic` between a `char` and an `int` is an `int` and you cannot store an `int` in a `char` without `explicit typecasting` - by which you tell to compiler that `I know what I'm doing, now do it for me`

So, you need to do a typecast: -

```
    char ch = 'a';
    if (ch >= 97 & ch <= 122) {
       ch = (char)(ch - 32);
    } 
    System.out.println(ch);  // Prints `A`
```

But, you have already `method` in `Character` class, that will do it for you: -

```
char ch = 'a';
ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
System.out.println(ch);  // Prints `A`
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ch = (char) (ch + 32);
```

if you're sure that ch + 32 won't be bigger than what a char can hold.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you trying to assign an int value (Ascii value) to the char. But you need to explicitly convert the result value int to char. Just cast int to char.

```
ch= (char) (ch+32);
ch= (char) (ch-32);
```

It will work with out any Exception.