# char arithmetic in Java

Tags: java

I wrote the code below to convert lowercase into uppercase and uppercase into lowercase, but it is not running properly. This code is triggering following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char
    at learn.Example.main(Example.java:20)
```

---

```
public class Example 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException
    {
        char ch;

        System.out.println("Enter an alphabet only: ");

        do
        {
            ch = (char) System.in.read();

            if (ch>='a' & ch <= 'z')
            {
                ch= ch-32;
                System.out.println(ch);
            }
            if (ch >='A' & ch <= 'Z')
            {
                ch = ch + 32;
                System.out.println(ch);
            }
        }
        while (ch != '.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
ch = ch - 32;
```

to

```
ch = (char) (ch - 32);
```

since the result of this arithmetic operator is an `int` and must be cast to `char` explicitly.

Similarly change

```
ch = ch + 32;
```

to

```
ch = (char) (ch + 32);
```

Comment: Also use `&&` instead of `&`.

Comment: @UmaKanth The code will work with `&` too, though using the short circuit version `&&` is usually better.

Answer (score 3):

Just need to `cast` it like this:

```
   ch= ch-32;
```

To:

```
   ch= (char) (ch-32);
```

And this:

```
  ch = ch + 32;
```

To:

```
 ch = (char) (ch + 32);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you trying to assign an int value (Ascii value) to the char. But you need to explicitly convert the result value int to char.
Just cast int to char.

```
ch= (char) (ch+32);
ch= (char) (ch-32);
```

It will work with out any Exception.

Comment: Yes, that is what i have told. I told to do explicit casting because the operation there returns int so if he want to store that back to char then he must give explicit casting.@Andy Turner

Comment: Thank you now  i have edited the solution.Thanks for correcting me.@Andy

Answer (score 0):

In Your code block (ch-32) and ch+32 ,it will return the int and you are assigning to char,you need to cast it to char explicitly.

for converting int to char belwo is code snippet.

If you  want to cast the value in the int, you can cast it using Java's typecast notation:

```
int i = 97; // 97 is 'a' in ASCII
char c = (char) i; // c is now 'a'
```

If you want to  transform the integer 1 into the character '1', you can do it like this:

```
if (i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
char c = Character.forDigit(i, 10);
....
}
```

and here your modified code are  ,

```
public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.IOException
        {
            char ch;

            System.out.println("Enter an alphabet only: ");

            do
            {
                ch = (char) System.in.read();

                if (ch>='a' & ch <= 'z')
                {
                    ch= (char) (ch-32);
                    System.out.println(ch);
                }
                if (ch >='A' & ch <= 'Z')
                {
                    ch = (char) (ch + 32);
                    System.out.println(ch);
                }
            }
            while (ch != '.');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are making any arithmetic operation on any literal then it will become an int, so:

- `ch + 32` and `ch - 32` both are int and you can't assign these int values to a character `ch`, that you are trying to do in your code.

So you need to typecast this int value to char, as:

- `ch = (char)(ch + 32)`  and   `ch = (char)(ch - 32)`